# Wrapping div around form

Tags: 7, forms

```
 function gng_unsubscribe_form($form,&$form_state) {
 $form['email'] = array(
 '#title' => 'Email',

'#type' => 'textfield',
 );
 $form['submit']=array(
 '#type'=>'submit',
 '#value'=>t('Unsubscribe'),
 '#prefix' => '<div class="btn-area">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>'
 );
 return $form;
 }
```

For a particular field I can add custom class using `#prefix` and `#suffix`, is there a way to add wrapping div around whole form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#form), #prefix & #suffix are valid properties of the form element, so you should be able to:

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div class="some-class">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```